# Restrict user scrolling in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-recyclerview

In my project I use a RecyclerView that I only want to scroll by calling the startSmoothScroll() method of the LayoutManager:

```
private fun next(){
    val layoutManager = pager.layoutManager as BattlePageLayoutManager
    layoutManager.startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller(layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition() + 1))
    layoutManager.finishScroll()
}
```

I do not want the user to be able to scroll manually, e. g. by swiping.

I already tried to achieve this through overriding the method onInterceptTouchEvent() of the parent FrameLayout.

```
    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        if (ev.actionMasked == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            startClickTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
            startX = ev.x
            startY = ev.y
        }        
        val allowEvent = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startClickTime) < 1000 && (startX-ev.x).absoluteValue < 15 && (startY-ev.y).absoluteValue < 15
        return !allowEvent
    }
```

That worked basically, but it occured that after double-tapping the View users are able to scroll by themselves.

Do you have any other ideas to approach this?

Comment: Is it `ViewPager` or `RecyclerView` that you want to block the scroll? I see that you are asking for `RecyclerView`, but I also see that your `layoutManager` is from `pager`.

Comment: It is a RecyclerView, but it works like a ViewPager. I do this, because I want to use the Android Paging Library. Is there a simple way of implementing these behavior with a ViewPager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Did you try overriding canScrollVertically() method in the LayoutManager?</strike>

```
mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()) {
    @Override
    public boolean canScrollVertically() {
        return false;
    }
};
```

**Edit:**
Create your own implementation of RecyclerView which it disables the touch event while scrolling is performing. Then you have to change the RecyclerView class in the xml file and Fragment/Activity with it.

Find here an example in Kotlin

```
class MyRecyclerView : RecyclerView {
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {}

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs) {}

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyle: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyle) {}

    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        return if (scrollState != RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) false else super.onInterceptTouchEvent(e)
    }
}
```

And in Java

```
public class MyRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {
    public MyRecyclerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyRecyclerView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyRecyclerView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        if(getScrollState() != SCROLL_STATE_IDLE)
            return false;
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but the smartSmoothScrolling method isn't usable too that way.

Comment: Create your own implementation of RecyclerView which it disables the touch event while scrolling is performing. Check the edit!

Comment: Unfortunately, the scrollState is always 0

Comment: mmm... I tried and for me worked... but I call `recyclerView.startSmoothScroll(...)` instead of `layoutManager.startSmoothScroll()`. I'll try later doing the same with the layoutManager. Maybe in `onInterceptTouchEvent` method you can check the `getLayoutManager().isSmoothScrolling()` and then disable the gestures

Comment: I found out, that the state in the 'onInterceptTouchEvent' is alway 0, but in the 'dispatchTouchEvent' not. Based on that I found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to block the user interaction with `RecyclerView`, not with `FrameLayout` itself.

Check [RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener).

In your `RecyclerView`, you can implement `OnItemTouchListener` and override every method to do nothing.

That will block the user interaction with `RecyclerView`, making scroll not happen.